# series sum of reciprocals of multiplications

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can someone recommend an approach to calculate this sum of series

$\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{(x-2)2}+\frac{1}{(x-3)3}+...+\frac{1}{(x/2)(x/2)}$

Trying to link to harmonic series, but could not be successful so far..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1}{i(x-i)}=\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{x-i}\right)$$

that is a link with harmonic serie.

Comment: nice, thanks...